# wrap a group of <tr></tr> table rows within a <tbody> tag using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm sort of new to Jquery, but hopefully I can get some help on an issue.

**I have created this code:**

```
if( jQuery.inArray(categoryList, movieArray) == -1 ){
         $('<h3 class="category"></h3>').html(categoryList).appendTo('#movieList');
          movieArray.push(categoryList);  
          $("#movieList").append("<thead><tr><th class='long'>" + txtTitle + "</th><th>" + txtLength + "</th><th>" + txtLanguage + "</th></thead>"); 
    }

    var rows = "<tr><td>" + title + "</td><td>" + movieTime + "</td><td>" + language + "</td></tr>";

    $("#movieList").append(rows);
});

    $('#movieList .category').each(function(){ 
        var $set = $(this).nextUntil(".category");
        $set.wrapAll('<div class="movieTable"><table class="table dataTable"></table></div>');
    });
```

Basically, I would like to be able to wrap the group of TR tags that get generated within the  tags. The reason is that I'd like to use the table sorter plugin, but it won't work unless the table distinguishes between THEAD and TBODY

Comment: How are you adding rows to a specific category? Because `$("#movieList").append(rows);` will always add rows to the bottom of `#movieList`.

Comment: here's my codepen http://codepen.io/willf/pen/bnjgu for what I have so far, with the exception of the xml file. I've added notes to each section in the script so you can see what I was trying to do. There probably is another way of doing this so the <tbody> tags show up, but I'm stumped

Comment: Can you share an example of the XML please

Comment: Sure, here's the new codepen link http://codepen.io/willf/pen/vibey - I've added the xml snippet in the JS section.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just append the table, then append the rows to the correct category? I don't know how this function is run, but I think this might work:

```
if( jQuery.inArray(categoryList, movieArray) == -1 ){
  $('<h3 class="category"></h3>').html(categoryList).appendTo('#movieList');
  movieArray.push(categoryList);
  $("#movieList").append("<div class='movieTable'><table class='table dataTable " + categoryList + "'><thead><tr><th class='long'>" + txtTitle + "</th><th>" + txtLength + "</th><th>" + txtLanguage + "</th></thead><tbody></tbody></table></div>");
}
$('table.' + categoryList).find('tbody').append("<tr><td>" + title + "</td><td>" + movieTime + "</td><td>" + language + "</td></tr>");
```

If this doesn't work, it would help if you provided a basic demo.